# AS3 How to add adMob to Adobe Flash/Animate?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6, animate.css

AS3 How to add adMob to Adobe Flash/Animate?

Please help me  to figure out how to add adMMob to my Actionscript 3 app. There isn't a  well-written documentation on how to do it. I only found a youtube video that explains it but still it was not well and fully described . for the  bits and pieces of information that I gathered, I managed to construct the following code, however it errors. Please help to reconstruct the code so I get it to work.

1. First I got Pozirk's AdMob Air Native Extension from github
2. I installed the AdMob.swc and the AdMob.ane files in the Advanced ActionScript settings
3. I created a class file called Main.as which contains the following code:

```
package {   
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdMob;
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdParams;
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdEvent;
var _admob: AdMob = new AdMob();
public class Main extends MovieClip{
    
        public function Main(){
        
            //> initialization of AdMob
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INIT_OK, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INIT_FAIL, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.BANNER_SHOW_OK, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.BANNER_SHOW_FAIL, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.BANNER_LEFT_APP, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.BANNER_OPENED, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.BANNER_CLOSED, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_SHOW_OK, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_SHOW_FAIL, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_CACHE_OK, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_CACHE_FAIL, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_LEFT_APP, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_OPENED, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_CLOSED, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.REWARDED_CACHE_FAIL, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.REWARDED_CACHE_OK, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.REWARDED_CLOSED, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.REWARDED_COMPLETED, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.REWARDED_LEFT_APP, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.REWARDED_OPENED, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.REWARDED_REWARDED, onEvent);
            _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.REWARDED_STARTED, onEvent);
            _admob.init();
        }
    }

}
```

4. I added this line to the script, it's sitting on the top root and not part of a function or anything else. I'm not sure if it's supposed to be nested somewhere.

`_admob.show("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111", AdParams.SIZE_SMART_BANNER, AdParams.HALIGN_CENTER, AdParams.VALIGN_BOTTOM);`

with this above settings when trying to compile the code I get the following error message:

> "Main.as, Line 1  5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one
> externally visible definition: _admob, Main"

1. Why I'm getting this error message?
2. Is this code is proper to run adMob?
3. am I missing something?

Comment: Please format your script sample to readability, so the lines are not crammed and all of them are properly indented.

Comment: I did but it didn't catch on for whatever reason.

Comment: can I edit my post? I don't see this option.

Comment: I found the itsy bitsy edit link and I re-edit my post like 500 times but the format only partially worked here. so please forgive the format of this post and try to help anyway. thank you.

Comment: ok on the 5001 it worked.

Comment: Moving variable declaration inside the class is a correct decision. That's why tidily formatted code is always better than messy one. Then, the error you get now, it's easily googlible, for example: https://www.thewhitewood.com/root-content-is-missing-from-package/

Answer (score 0):

I made a change to the package and moved the `var` inside the class section.

```
package {   
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdMob;
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdParams;
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip{
    var _admob: AdMob = new AdMob();
        public function Main(){
```

I also realized that I probably need to put this statement in a function. which I did. but now I get this error message when compiling the app.

`the swf file specified as the root content is missing`

```
function onEvent():void
{
    _admob.show("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111", AdParams.SIZE_SMART_BANNER, AdParams.HALIGN_CENTER, AdParams.VALIGN_BOTTOM);
}
```

Comment: link your main class to the main class of adobe animate (just write the name of your class) also in the ActionScript setting/library path add ANE/SWC of Pozirk's AdMob Air Native Extension and test it on a mobile device